# XAxis repeats itself in Rechart's ScatterChart when type="category"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, recharts

In the following picture/code there should only be one occurrence of hi, hello and bye. Any ideas on why it's repeating?

Edit in browser here : http://jsfiddle.net/ndLhnegs/318/ Edit: I made another, simpler example here : http://jsfiddle.net/7coegorj/2/

[image]

React Rechart component:

```
const {Scatter, ScatterChart, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const Chart = React.createClass({
  render(){
      const selected = [
        {value:'obj1',label:'Obj1'},
        {value:'obj2',label:'Obj2'},
        {value:'obj3',label:'Obj3'},
        {value:'obj4',label:'Obj4'},
      ]
      const scatters = selected.map((s) => {
        let data = [
          {x:'hi',y:Math.random() * 10},
          {x:'hello',y:Math.random() * 10},
          {x:'bye',y:Math.random() * 10},
        ]
        return (
          <Scatter
            key={s.label}
            name={s.label}
            data={data}
            fill='#000'
            line
            shape="cross" />
        );
      });
      return (
        <ScatterChart width={600} height={400} margin={{ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 }}>
          <XAxis  dataKey='x' name='Macro' />
          <YAxis type="number" dataKey={'y'} name='Grams' unit='g' />
          <CartesianGrid />
          <Tooltip cursor={{ strokeDasharray: '3 3' }} />
          <Legend />
          {scatters}
        </ScatterChart >
      );
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <Chart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Submitted a GitHub issue here - https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1034

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, I believe you can use `allowDuplicatedCategories={false}` which is in the documentation here: http://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis#allowDuplicatedCategory

Comment: it is known as `allowDuplicatedCategory` in version 2.7, so always check the documentation because the attribute name might change.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where `allowDuplicatedCategores={false}` unsorts the data in the graph, you have to transform the data for each scatter source to have the same domain points as all sources but with null for each point not corresponding to the source (has to be null otherwise it will plot a point at 0).

ie.

if sourceA has a single point at `(hello, 1)` but sourceB has two points `(hello, 0)` and `(bye, 2)`, they must be transformed to:

```
sourceA = [{ x: 'hello', y: null }, { x: 'bye', y: 1 }];
sourceB = [{ x: 'hello', y: 0 }, { x: 'bye', y: 2 }];
```